# Keeping columns (but skiping index) in unpivot in geopandas data.frame

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas, data-munging

I'd like to use to some 'unpivot' method in python to reshape my pandas data frame. However, one of the columns that I want to keep is a 'geometry' column of geopandas after reshaping it. My dataset has 5 columns and there's no way to put this 'geometry' column as index and then resetting the index just as I tried below:

```
us_tidy[['Name','STATE_ABBR','geometry','Year','Income']].pivot_table(index = ['Name','STATE_ABBR', 'geometry'], columns = 'Year', values = 'Income').reset_index()
```

Is there a way to reshape the dataset in this wide way and keeping some columns but AVOIDING to have this index part (at least for this specific column)???

Here's some lines of the geopandas dataset:

[Geopandas Lines Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nIfBw.png)

In addition, here's some reproducible example:

```
import pandas as pd
import pysal as ps   
import geopandas as gpd

csv_path = ps.examples.get_path('usjoin.csv')
usjoin = pd.read_csv(csv_path)

years = list(range(1929, 2010))                  
cols_to_calculate = list(map(str, years))

shp_path = ps.examples.get_path('us48.shp')
us48_map = gpd.read_file(shp_path)
us48_map = us48_map[['STATE_FIPS','STATE_ABBR','geometry']]
us48_map.STATE_FIPS = us48_map.STATE_FIPS.astype(int)
df_map = us48_map.merge(usjoin, on='STATE_FIPS')

# Making the dataset tidy
us_tidy = pd.melt(df_map, 
                  id_vars=['Name', 'STATE_FIPS', 'STATE_ABBR', 'geometry'],
                  value_vars=cols_to_calculate, 
                  var_name='Year', 
                  value_name='Income').\
                  sort_values('Name')

us_tidy[['Name','STATE_ABBR', 'geometry', 'Year','Income']].\
                 pivot_table(index = ['Name','STATE_ABBR', 'geometry'], 
                             columns = 'Year', 
                             values = 'Income')
```

The error message is:
TypeError: unhashable type: 'Polygon'

Best regards,
Renan

Comment: Could you share a few rows of some example data?

Comment: Sure! I updated the question with a link for some geopandas lines! Thanks!

Comment: Could you add example data into your question as text instead of images? We can't copy-paste from screenshots :P

Comment: Also, what goes wrong when you try to run your `pivot_table` command?

Comment: Hi, Peter! Sure, thanks a lot for the advice! I updated my question with a reproducible example! Best, Renan